# Write html content outside script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code which will **fetch** the **text** from **JSON** & **onclick** text, display popup box in page.... Now I need to give options to change font-family, font color etc....

I need to add lot of HTML code in the place of **Content**....

Is there any way to keep the "content" code in HTML & separate it from script?

[image]

**JSON** :

```
{        
          "font" : "Arian",
          "x" : 201,
          "y" : 461,          
          "type" : "text",          
          "text" : "Good Food",          
          "name" : "edit_good_1"
}
```

**script**

```
const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('.container').append(
            '<a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +            
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +            
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> content <a href="javascript:void(0)" ' +
            'onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close</a></div> <div>'
        );
        document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'
```

codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/OGbGwN

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/z6eyq4j3/

Comment: What you can do is create a div and make it display none. Inside this div you can place your repeating html and in JavaScript once you have the data you can clone the html content from DOM and render the data in the cloned HTML. Finally append this new cloned HTML in your DOM.
E.g.
`let template = $("div.container").find("a").clone(); $(template).attr('id', layer.name)`

Comment: @DeepakSingh Thanks for suggestion, but will these kind of code `layer.x `  work in html :  ? also i included those code in forloop....

Comment: `layer.x` you have to write in JavaScript. See the idea is that you'll be having a dummy HTML rendered initially in DOM with no/dummy data. Under the JavaScript section now you'll first clone the dummy html and then get the data to be shown from your source. Afterwards you have to simply populate the data and append it in DOM. All of this will be done in JS only.

Comment: @DeepakSingh sorry,  i am new to these things, i will try....

Comment: No issues. It's very simple once you'll implement this. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a separate html file template, and add there some variables, like:

```
<pre>
<div id="{layer.name}">
<a href="{link}">{link.name}</a>
</div>
....
</pre>
```

And in the script you can replace your variables with data:

```
$.get("/ulrOfYourHtmlTemplate").done(function(template) {
   $('.container').append(template.replace("{layer.name}",layer.name).replace("{link}",link).replace("{link.name}", link.name))
})
```

Comment: Thanks, can we make it work in same html file instead of separate html file ?

Comment: sure, just put it in a JS varaible like text, and replace your variables later.
var template = '<div id="{id}">{varaible}</div>';